# VisJS on edit edge mode. How to allow just one side edition?

Tags: editmode, vis.js

I have a [VisJs](http://visjs.org) network where the edges leaving the nodes are handled programatically. So, the user should not be able to change the node from where a edge comes from. However, the user is free to point the edge to any other node. More specifically, in the [VisJs edit edge mode](http://visjs.org/docs/network/#methodManipulation), I'd like to allow the user to edit just the `to` connection. How can I do this?

I'm starting the edit mode through the API.

```
network.editEdgeMode();
```

Answer (score 2):

try to use this definition in the manipulation section:

```
editEdge: function (data, callback) {
              var orgigEdge = edges.get(data.id);

              if (data.from !== orgigEdge.from) {
                alert('you cannot change the source of the edge');
                callback(null);
              }
              else {
                callback(data);
              }
          },
```

see if this example feets your requirements (just click on the edge).

https://plnkr.co/edit/EakgOk9HeNTJGpRkSy9q?p=preview